# WebAPI : 'IHttpActionResult' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, lambda

Good morning, this is my first question in the community. I'm working with the C# WebAPI framework and I'm trying to change all my controllers' methods to be asynchronous. My controllers extend from a ***GenericController*** which has a method (CallWF) that calls methods from a DLL and it also handles all kind of exceptions.

> Layer1/Controllers <===> Layer2/GenericController.CallWF <===>
>   Layer3/DLL Methods

**Here is my GenericController.CallWF Code:**

```
protected IHttpActionResult CallWF<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(action.Invoke());
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        return( BadRequest( GetMyExceptionMessage(e1)) );
    }
}

protected IHttpActionResult CallWF(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action.Invoke();
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        return( BadRequest( GetMyExceptionMessage(e1)) );
    }
}
```

**And here is a example of a controller's method.**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
[Route("MyMethodA")]
public IHttpActionResult MyMethodA(int arg1)
{
    return CallWF<string>(
    () => {
        return repositoryA.itsMethodA(arg1);
    });
}
```

As you can see, the method is synchronous. Now I want to turn it asynchronous. After reading some websites explaining how to make asynchronous functions, this is what I thought it would be the solution.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
[Route("MyMethodA")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyMethodA(int arg1)
{
    return await CallWF<string>(
    () => {
        return repositoryA.itsMethodA(arg1);
    });
}
```

**But doing this, it occurs the follow error:**

> CS1061    'IHttpActionResult' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IHttpActionResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Trying another approach, I tried creating a new CallWF function for async.
**Here is the approach made.**

```
protected async Task<IHttpActionResult> CallWFAsync<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    try
    {
        IHttpActionResult res = Ok( action.Invoke());
        return await Ok( action.Invoke() );
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
       return ( BadRequest(GetMyExceptionMessage(e1)) );
    }
}
```

**And doing this, it gives me the title error.**

> CS1061    'OkNegotiatedContentResult' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'OkNegotiatedContentResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas to solve this? Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: The exception messages explain that you are trying to return something that is not await-able. There is no need for `await` just return the `Task`. Unless there is actual need for asynchronous functionality in method you can simply return the `Task`. You could use `Task.FromResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception messages explain that you are trying to return something that is not await-able. There is no need for `await` just return the `Task`. Unless there is actual need for asynchronous functionality in method you can simply return the `Task` using `Task.FromResult`

Referencing this article: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

> Tip: If you have a very simple asynchronous method, you may be able to
>   write it without using the await keyword (e.g., using
>   Task.FromResult). If you can write it without await, then you should
>   write it without await, and remove the async keyword from the method.
>   A non-async method returning Task.FromResult is more efficient than an
>   async method returning a value.

Using your first attempt, it can be refactored to this ...

```
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
[Route("MyMethodA")]
public Task<IHttpActionResult> MyMethodA(int arg1) {
    var result = CallWF<string>(
    () => {
        return repositoryA.itsMethodA(arg1);
    });

    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

In your second approach if you wanted to convert the `CallWF` method, you can use the same approach

```
protected Task<IHttpActionResult> CallWFAsync<T>(Func<T> action) {
    IHttpActionResult result = null;
    try
    {
        result = Ok(action.Invoke());
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        result = BadRequest(GetMyExceptionMessage(e1));
    }
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

And this would now allow you to do what were trying to do in your first example by calling the `CallWFAsync` method

```
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
[Route("MyMethodA")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyMethodA(int arg1)
{
    return await CallWFAsync<string>(
    () => {
        return repositoryA.itsMethodA(arg1);
    });
}
```

Comment: Everything you said worked. First of all, I got informed that all repositories' methods were synsynchronous, so obvious I did not need to create an auxiliar method to handle. Then I try your code and it works. Thanks a lot.